# PHP output bcc object values from phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

I'm using phpmailer and would like to output the bcc email addresses that it sent to for logging purposes. ($mail->AddBCC())

I can output the $mail object with a simple print_r($mail)... I would like to only output with:

`print_r($mail->all_recipients:private);`

but that does not work.
I've tried:

`print_r($mail->{'all_recipients:private'});`

but that also does not work.

`print_r($mail);`

shows:

```
[AltBody] => 
[WordWrap] => 0
[Mailer] => smtp
[Sendmail] => /usr/sbin/sendmail
[PluginDir] => 
[ConfirmReadingTo] => 
[Hostname] => 
[MessageID] => 
[Host] => smtp.gmail.com
[Port] => 587
...
[all_recipients:private] => Array
    (
        [exampl1@test.com] => 1
        [exampl2@test.com] => 1
        [exampl3@test.com] => 1
    )
...
```

Comment: `print_r($mail['all_recipients:private'])` ?

Comment: `:private` means that `all_recipients` is a PRIVATE attribute of the phpmailer object. it's not part of the key name. that means you can't access it from "outside" the object. You're only seeing it in the print_r output because print_r is for debug purposes and can display private attributes like that.

Comment: If the `bcc` property is being reported as `private`, you're running a very old version of PHPMailer as it was changed to `protected` some years ago; [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)

Comment: Yes... I was running a very old version. I updated and now the data is protected. However, I still get: "cannot access protected property” - which I assume is the answer. I cannot access the data this way and used the getAllRecipientAddresses() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `print_r($mail->getBccAddresses());` to get the array of BCC addresses, as found in [the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L3653) and [the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_getBccAddresses).

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: You want me to add boilerplate waffle "to get the array of BCC addresses from the mail object, call `$mail->getBccAddresses()`", as if it adds anything, especially since the OP has already shown that they a) know how to call methods on the object and b) know how to output stuff? The name of the function is the *only* thing the OP is missing.

Comment: I'm asking you to consider something. Whether it's some info on exactly what format they're received in, or anything else that might be useful when calling the function. Bear in mind that the OP likely isn't the only one who'll see this answer when trying to solve the problem.

Comment: I was running a very old version which seemed to not have getBccAddresses()? I updated and now the data is protected. However, I still get: "cannot access protected property” - which I assume is the answer. I cannot access the data this way and used the getAllRecipientAddresses() method.

Comment: Good that you updated, but did you actually read my answer? Call `getBccAddresses()` instead of trying to access the `bcc` property directly; that way you will not get the error.